# What multi-port wall USB-chargers exist which support QC 3.0?

Tags: usb, power-supply

I'm looking for a US wall-plug charger which supports Qualcomm Quick Charging 3.0 (QC 3.0) or later  The trouble is that while there a re many chargers with one QC 3.0 port, and other 5V 2.1A ports, I need multiple QC 3.0 ports.

Here are the requirements:
*The charger must...*

- be compatible with US plugs
- have at least 2 QC 3.0 ports
- be able to put out power equal to the number of QC3.0 ports * 24 watts
- have the option to be shipped to at least the lower 48 US states.

*It would be nice if the charger could...*

- Have 4 QC3.0 ports
- be under 75$ US

There is no preference to whether the charger uses USB C or USB A, nor is there a preference to whether the charger is corded or direct plug.

The closest thing I found is the following, but I  would highly prefer a 4-port charger:
[dual port QC 3.0 charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TV3ST69)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseus GaN 120W PD charger would be the one to consider.

https://a.aliexpress.com/_BPxnjT

It doesn't exactly has 4 ports, but it has 3 ports that all support QC and some support PD. I have a cheaper 65W model, which can support 2 ports working in PD or QC mode simultaneously, but doesn't support QC on all ports at the same time, but I think this one is much more powerful, and so should be able to support all three ports working in QC mode, especially since it says the three ports can deliver "60w+30w+30w".